# Hide default postgre and template databases from end users

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to secure the Postgre database and one thing I noticed that users after logging via LDAP password can see inside the default 3 databases in the list of databases.

1. template0
2. template1
3. postgres

How can I hide these databases from end users?

Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean "people" and "see"

Comment: I have added few clarifications

Answer (score 0):

- `template0` is the stock database. It's not supposed to be touched.
- `template1` is the system's database that a new database clones.
- `postgres` is a default database, it's normally what you connect to if you want use `CREATE USER` or `CREATE DATABASE` when you're getting your system up and going.

You certainly don't *need* the postgres database, from [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/manage-ag-templatedbs.html)

> Note: template1 and template0 do not have any special status beyond the fact that the name template1 is the default source database name for CREATE DATABASE. For example, one could drop template1 and recreate it from template0 without any ill effects. This course of action might be advisable if one has carelessly added a bunch of junk in template1. **(To delete template1, it must have pg_database.datistemplate = false.)**
>
> The postgres database is also created when a database cluster is initialized. This database is meant as a default database for users and applications to connect to. It is simply a copy of template1 and **can be dropped** and recreated if necessary.

So my guess is you can safely nuke `postgres` and `template1`, and likely if you don't want to ever create any databases ever `template0`. However it's not clear what you plan to accomplish.